# Is it possible to use "Flash channels" to send non-transactional data?

Tags: transaction, iota-network, flash-channel

Is it possible to use "Flash channels" to send non-transactional data,
A.K.A 'zero-value' transaction type which simply broadcasts a message or data?

If so, is it free? And how to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not simply broadcast a message or data without Flash Channels?

Comment: because it is faster

Comment: No, it's not... Where did you get the impression, that it would be?

Comment: flash channels make transactions faster.
https://blog.iota.org/instant-feeless-flash-channels-88572d9a4385

Comment: They enable the transacting of Iotas without doing Proof Of Work (doing POW takes a long time). But for sending data over the Internet (or any network), you don't have to do POW. You just send the data.

Comment: i want that this data to be verified into the Tangle.

Comment: I got you now. Answer incoming.

Comment: Hi @user3785971 please include your clarifications from the comments into the question with  [edit]. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Transactions made in flash channels are not written to the Tangle.**

There are only two events that are stored:

- opening of a flash channel
- closing of a flash channel

When opening a flash channel, two (or more) entities, let's call them Alice and Bob, lock up Iotas.

- Alice and Bob [open a Flash Channel](http://blog.iota.org/instant-feeless-flash-channels-88572d9a4385#7926) (while still online)
- Alice and Bob loose connection to any full nodes but are still connected with each other
- now Alice can [send IOTAs to Bob and vice versa](http://blog.iota.org/instant-feeless-flash-channels-88572d9a4385#4761), **POW is not required**
- once they reconnect to a full node, they [close the channel](https://blog.iota.org/instant-feeless-flash-channels-88572d9a4385#b295)

---

This is why it wouldn't make sense to "broadcast a message or data" via Flash Channels. It would be just as good as broadcasting it without flash channels.

Comment: Is it possible to store the data that flows from one address to another into a private blockchain/DAG since it is not being stored on the Tangle ?

Comment: Of course, it's just data. You can do anything you want with it. But you would have to pay fees/do POW (whatever the private blockchain/DAG requires you to do in order to store data).